# Android close all fragments onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with about 10 fragments in each fragment there is an AsyncTask with ProgressDialog I need  away to close  all fragments when I click back Button 
it's closed but the ProgressDialog  still visible especially  when I transfer between fragments 
here is the code I use

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
      if(fragmentManager!=null){
            for(int i = 0; i < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
                fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            }}
                                 }
```

also when I debug I found that it enters onCreateView for each fragment I open when I press back button although I use `transaction.replace` method to transfer between fragments.

Comment: Try removing `addToBackStack` when you are transitioning your fragments.

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am clearing stack by following method.

```
  public void popBackStackTillEntry(int entryIndex) {

    if (getSupportFragmentManager() == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() <= entryIndex) {
        return;
    }
    FragmentManager.BackStackEntry entry = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(
            entryIndex);
    if (entry != null) {
        Utilities.sDisableFragmentAnimations = true;
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(entry.getId(),
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }


}
```

Clear upto 1 means all fragments will be removed from stack and only single fragment will remain in stack.

Usage 
         popBackStackTillEntry(1);

Answer (score 1):

This is my kotlin solution:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
   supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
}
```

You can pass null for the name as it is nullable.